# fp-section pushing elements downwards

Tags: html, css

A `div` I didn't create but is viewable when you look at the source code, is pushing my elements downwards in my one page scroller. I tried to remove the height but then the whole pages turns into chaos, so probably it has an important function.

How can I remove the height of it without ruining my pages?

Here you can see the class name of the div.

```html
            
          <div class="section fp-section fp-table active fp-completely" id="section1" data-anchor="page1"       style="height: 2491px;"><div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:2491px;">
          <div class="overlayer">
            
          <!-- This code above is inside my html but without the fp- section
          fp-table active fp-completely with a height of 2491.
          -->
            
          </div>
          <!-- Content wrapper inside the landings section -->
          
            <div class="content-wrapper">
              <div class="content">
                <h1 class="h1dif"> Dif Report </h1><br>
                <p class="pland"> Quest for innovators<br> with bright ideas. </p><br>
                <a href=""><img class="badge1" src="Content website/androidBadge.png" width="150px" height="60x"></a>
                <a href=""><img class="badge2" src="Content website/appleBadge.png" width="130px" height="40x"></a>           
              </div>
            <div class="mockups">
              <img class="mockpic" src="Content website/mockups.png">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Right Dot Navigation -->
          <div class="dotstyle-scaleup">
            <ul>
              <li class="current1"><a href="#page1"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page2"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page3"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page4"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page5"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div></div>
          <!-- Content wrapper inside the landings section -->
          
            <div class="content-wrapper">
              <div class="content">
                <h1 class="h1dif"> Dif Report </h1><br>
                <p class="pland"> Quest for innovators<br> with bright ideas. </p><br>
                <a href=""><img class="badge1" src="Content website/androidBadge.png" width="150px" height="60x"></a>
                <a href=""><img class="badge2" src="Content website/appleBadge.png" width="130px" height="40x"></a>           
              </div>
            <div class="mockups">
              <img class="mockpic" src="Content website/mockups.png">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Right Dot Navigation -->
          <div class="dotstyle-scaleup">
            <ul>
              <li class="current1"><a href="#page1"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page2"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page3"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page4"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page5"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div></div>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
              <div class="content">
                <h1 class="h1dif"> Dif Report </h1></br>
                <p class="pland"> Quest for innovators<br> with bright ideas. </p><br>
                <a href="" ><img class="badge1" src="Content website/androidBadge.png" width="150px" height="60x"></a>
                <a href=""><img class="badge2" src="Content website/appleBadge.png" width="130px" height="40x"></a>           
              </div>
            <div class="mockups">
              <img class="mockpic" src="Content website/mockups.png">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Right Dot Navigation -->
          <div class="dotstyle-scaleup">
            <ul>
              <li class="current1"><a href="#page1"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page2"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page3"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page4"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#page5"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code?

Comment: What about the JS initialisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your HTML doctype:

**From:**

`<doctype html>`

**To:**

`<!doctype html>`

I noticed on your website that the document will fix itself if you resize the window. There was an issue raised on **[Github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/478)** about this, and it turned out to be an issue with doctype as well as versions of jQuery etc.

Comment: Hm, seems fixed. Yeah I noticed that when I open source code window it position it self.

Comment: @CodePirate Fantastic - don't forget to mark as the correct answer ;)